# What can I Use Instead of @Html.action?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have BaseController which I pass my header with @Html.Action but I am trying to pass my UI elements inside other controller's actions via BaseController.

BaseController :
`var UIElements = new BL.UIElements().GetUIElementsListForWeb(language);
 var MenuItems = new BL.Menu().GetMenuListForWeb(language, true, null, null);`

HomeLayout : `@Html.Action("_header", "Base")
                @RenderBody()`

The problem is RenderBody() is trying to pass model first. And UIElements inside view (`@Model.UIElements.contactUs`)
is coming null. I dont want to repeat my code and put UIelements inside every controller's action.

What should I do. How can I render my partial view first?

I hope you can understand my problem.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate those UI elements in this `Header` action:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Header(string language)
{
    var UIElements = new BL.UIElements().GetUIElementsListForWeb(language);
    var MenuItems = new BL.Menu().GetMenuListForWeb(language, true, null, null);
    var model = new HeaderModel{
        UIElements = UIElements,
        MenuItems = MenuItems 
    }

    return PartialView("_header", model)
}

public class HeaderModel
{
   public IList<UIElement> UIElements {get; set;} //list of UI Elements
   public IList<MenuItem> MenuItem{get; set;} //list of MenuItems
}
```

In your Layout you can use it

```
@Html.Action("Header", "Base" new {language = "en"}) //set your language parameter here
```

Comment: I am already doing that as you mentioned. But I want to use those UIElements into my view which is created inside RenderBody().

Comment: I did define a method in BaseController and I am using it where I want to get UIElements. Thanks your help. I solved it.